# yarn file cannot be found

Tags: yarnpkg

I installed yarn however when I try to use it I get the following problem:

```
fangio@fangio-UX305LA:~/Documents/UGent/Master2/S2/2_Datavisualisatie/datavis-project$ sudo npm install -g yarn
/usr/local/bin/yarnpkg -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
/usr/local/bin/yarn -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
/usr/local/lib
└── yarn@1.15.2 

fangio@fangio-UX305LA:~/Documents/UGent/Master2/S2/2_Datavisualisatie/datavis-project$ yarn install
bash: /usr/bin/yarn: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Comment: At first glance it looks like it creates links in `/usr/local/bin/` and is trying to install from `/usr/bin/`.

Comment: yes but how I fix this? Because I need to yarn install in the project I have made

Comment: I hesitate to venture too many suggestions for something I don't use, but you could try going where it expects to find it and create a symlink to where it really is.

Comment: What does your `$PATH` look like?